# XSL-FO - is it possible to automatically format sourcecode?

Tags: xsl-fo, pretty-print

Can this be done? I have a element `<programlisting>` with a source code or XML part and I want to make it look nice. The only solution I found is to add `white-space="pre"` in the transformation and format the XML manualy. But the painful thing is autoformat in the Eclipse IDE which ruins the manual attempt every time I use it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are producing a PDF. Is it for e-reading or print?
Or to put it differently do you need need users to select/highlight the code and copy?
If not you may consider using images to preserve the layout - hardly an ideal solution, but it will look as you want it to.
What language is the source code? 
Are you using Docbook (it looks like you are)
Are you wrapping your code inside CDATA?

Comment: I guess they don't need to copy the text. Also, I don't want images there - what if I need to change something? In that case I would have to create the whole image from scratch. The language is Java or XML. And I don't use Docbook, I created a custom XSL-FO transformation and named the tags like in Docbook (don't ask me why I haven't used Docbook instead, I have reasons :))